# SQL query to effectively have a "WHERE CLAUSE" after GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if it is possible to select all unique rows (by doing a group by columnname) where another column doesn't contain specific values.  EG:

```
users table
+-------+-----------+
| NAME  | COUNTRY   |
+-------+-----------+
| Bob   | Australia |
+-------+-----------+
| Bob   | America   |
+-------+-----------+
| Steve | Australia |
+-------+-----------+
| Sam   | Australia |
+-------+-----------+
| Sam   | America   |
+-------+-----------+
```

What I'm looking to do is get all rows grouped by NAME where COUNTRY doesn't contain America.

**PSUEDO-SQL**:  SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY Name WHERE COUNTRY NOT LIKE 'America' (obviously this doesn't work but it's for clarification)

Output from above:

```
+-------+-----------+
| NAME  | COUNTRY   |
+-------+-----------+
| Steve | Australia |
+-------+-----------+
```

Can this be done or am I approaching this the wrong way?

**EDIT**:  I am unsure of how to word title so if someone has a better suggestion please update it/let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `select *` with `group by`.  Perhaps you want:

```
SELECT name, country
FROM users 
WHERE COUNTRY NOT LIKE 'America'
```

Or if you want `name`s that are not in `'America'`:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(COUNTRY LIKE 'America') = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, country FROM table WHERE country != 'America'
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT name, country
FROM users
WHERE country <> 'America'
GROUP BY country
HAVING count(name) = 1

EDIT: This is my first ever Stack Overflow post so open to constructive feedback. Look forward to hearing your thoughts.